# How to attach to a process with pydevd (*without* using pycharm/eclipse)

Tags: python, pydev

The [documentation](https://github.com/fabioz/PyDev.Debugger) on the github project is pretty scanty, but what I've tried so far is installing `pydevd` in my virtualenv, running some random script, and then running `python venv/pydevd_attach_to_process/attach_pydevd.py --pid xxxx`.

When I do that, the stderr of the process I'm trying to attach to reports `[Errno 111] Connection refused`, presumably because it's trying to attach to a debug server.  It's extremely unclear, however, how and where to start that server! Reading the `pydevd` source has not been super enlightening, either (there are some references to a `dev_appserver.py` file that doesn't seem to exist in the installation).

Answer (score 1):

Well, the docs aren't there because it can't really be used alone, you're expected to use it with an IDE to actually show you the UI (which the debugger would connect to)...

i.e.: using PyDev to attach to a process you would open the debug perspective and then choose "Attach to Process", which would then start the client on the PyDev side and call `attach_pydevd.py` with the proper pid, at which point it would connect back and start the debug session.